# How to transform SQL result with complex JSON column containing dots in properties using Azure Data Factory?

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

Using an Azure Data Factory Flow I'm reading data from an Azure SQL database.
The result set has some simple columns, such as `Uid nvarchar(100)` but one column is JSON content `Json nvarchar(max)`.

The JSON content structure looks like this (there is one JSON document per row):

```json
{
  key: "Foo",
  dt.topic : "Foo Bar"
}
```

I'm now trying to transform the JSON string of the result set into a parsed JSON object using a "Parse Transform" containing both, `key` and `dt.topic`. I can successfully map `key` using the expression `(key as string)`.

But how can I map `dt.topic`? This doesn't work:

`(dt.topic as string)`

The moment I add a property with with a dot in it, there are red squigglies all over the place in the editor and if I decide to "Save and finish" I get the error "Expression type could not be evaluated, correct the expression."

Interestingly, using "Detect type" as suggested in the comments would add the properties just like I did, using the dot notation, resulting in the very same error.

Comment: Hi @Krumelur, can you please post the error you are getting?

Comment: Click on the "Define complex type" link in the Parse transformation's "Output column type" property. Inside the expression builder is a "detect data type" button. Click that and see what data type definition ADF uses there.

Comment: @NiharikaMoola-MT check updated post

Comment: @Krumelur, Can you try including your property with dot withing in braces ex: `({dt.topic} as string)`

Comment: Aweseom @NiharikaMoola-MT ! Make that an answer! It must be the only thing I did not try. I tried to escape using (), [], \, "", and '' :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column name with special characters should be included within braces `{}` in the Azure data factory.

Example:

To parse the JSON value with dot in the property name, the property name should be used within braces `{}`.

`({dt.topic} as string)`

[image]